# Как работает ScriptEngineManager и ScriptEngine?

Tags: java, математика, приведение

Какое-то время назад преобразовывал с помощью этих элементов математическое выражение, записанное в виде строки в численный тип, примерно следующим образом:
Есть строка str значение которой задаёт пользователь (например cos(x)) и числа a, b, n значение которых тоже задаёт пользователь, программа преобразует строку в другую строку (в данном случае `str = str.replaceAll("cos","Math.cos").replaceAll("((x))","(sm)");`) 
Затем происходит следующее:

```
    ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager(); //что происходит здесь и как это работает?
    ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn"); //что происходит здесь, как это работает и почему тип принимаемого значения "nashorn"?

    double h = (b-a)/n;
    double sum = 0;
    double res;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a+=h;
        engine.put("sm", a); // что происходит здесь?
        sum += (double) engine.eval(str); // как строка приводится к численному типу, когда она даже не число?
    res = h*sum;
```

P.S. В полной версии программа рассчитывала значение определённого интеграла по формуле прямоугольника

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java существует возможность подключать сторонние скриптовые движки. Делается это при помощи [ScriptEngineManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html) через механизм [Service Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service_Provider). Если говорить простыми словами, ты можешь написать java-приложение, которое будет исполнять, к примеру, Python-код (см [пример](https://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#using-jsr-223)). Можно подключить и javascript-движок. Одним из таких движков как раз является **[Nashorn](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA_JavaScript))** (есть ещё [Rhino](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino)). Кроме того, он поставляется в стандартном наборе JDK. Более того, в Jdk8 есть даже [встроенный web-браузер](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

Конкретно по твоему примеру в цикле выполняется **javascript** код  (тут неплохо бы добавить в вопрос реальное содержимое `str`) наверно содержащий следующее выражение

```js
//var x =...;//значение приходит из Java 
var res=cos(x);
return res;
```

Но [Nashorn](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA_JavaScript)) не знает о функции `cos`, в отличии от Firefox или Chrome. Поэтому происходит подмена `cos` на `Math.cos`. Плюс идёт подмена имени переменной `x` на `sm`, что на мой взгляд кажется сомнительным, можно же просто передавать сразу значение для x при помощи `engine.put("x", a);`. В итоге получается javascript-код:

```
//var sm =...;//значение приходит из Java при помощи `engine.put("sm", a);`
var res=Math.cos(sm);
return res;
```

который и идёт на выполнение в движок [Nashorn](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA_JavaScript)).

Что касательно кастования к `double` в

```java
sum += (double) engine.eval(str);
```

Здесь явно есть проблемы, т.к. согласно сигнатуре метода [ScriptEngine#eval](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)) возвращается тип `Object`. Более корректно было бы кастовать к типу `Number` и потом извлекать примитив при помощи `doubleValue` примерно так:

```java
sum += ((Number) engine.eval(str)).doubleValue();
```